# Firestore Firebase Database Rule, enabling admin to write

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Hi people i need help with enabling users to read everything but not write. And enabling admin to write and read everything.

I have users collection with documents, each document has role which if its an admin account it says role = 'admin' otherwise it says 'regular'

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if get(/databases/users/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 'admin';
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote this but its not solving anything

---------UPDATE----------

This was a fix for me, thanks.

get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))

But i am still not able to do anything from client side.
I checked in console with playground mode and rule is actually fine, it returns true if its admin uid. I am guessing it is a client side problem because it probably doesnt read uid. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your rules:

```
get(/databases/users/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))
```

should be

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))
```

Comment: Still not working for me, any idea what could be a problem?

Comment: @MilanNesovic What is the query/write you are trying to perform? Note that with your current rules, a user can't write their own user data.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. ([Official Firestore Security Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started))

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 'admin';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason its still not working for me, i tried that one earlier. Do you have any idea what else could be a problem? Reading is fine, but not even admin can write.